# Почему при удалении обработчика цвет фона ссылки не меняется?

Tags: javascript, html, события

Использую только Js.По заданию, пhи  клике на ссылку, её фон должен менять цвет на красный, при клике на следующую или предыдущую убирает у текущей выбранной ссылки фон и подсвечивает выбранную

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

    </style>
    <div>
        <a href="first">FirstLink</a><br><br>
        <a href="second">SecondLink</a><br><br>
        <a href="third">ThirdLink</a><br><br>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script>
let links=document.querySelectorAll("a"),
    p=document.querySelector("p")
links.forEach(link=>{
    link.addEventListener("click",func)

})

function func(){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.style.background='red'
    if(this.nextSibling===event.target||this.previousSibling===event.target){
     this.removeEventListener('click',func)
    }
    p.innerHTML=`Your click on link:${this.innerHTML}`
}
</script>

</htm
```

Comment: в почему при удалении обработчика должен меняться цвет? Как они связаны?

Comment: а разве при удалении обработчика фон по умолчанию не станет бесцветным?

Comment: С чего бы ему становиться бесцветным? За фон отвечает свойство `background` в `css`, при удалении обработчика - это свойство не меняется.

Comment: у меня так-то есть решение рабочее.. но я надеялся, что можно через установку и удаление обработчиков эту задачу решить

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, условия типа `this.nextSibling===event.target` никогда не будут верны, потому что `event.target` в данном обработчике обработчике всегда будет равно `this`. То есть в данном коде и обработчик никогда не удаляется.

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, зачем вообще удалять обработчик, если нужно, чтобы он постоянно был наготове?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так. Удалил лишнее, чтобы было похоже на шаблон.

```html
<a href="#">FirstLink</a>
<a href="#">SecondLink</a>
<a href="#">ThirdLink</a>
<style>
    .red-bg{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => {
        a.addEventListener("click", func);
    });
    function func(){
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName("red-bg")[0];
        if (x) {
            x.classList.remove("red-bg");
        }
        this.classList.add("red-bg");
    }
</script>
```

Здесь не нужно искать все элементы и убирать у каждого фон, достаточно найти 1 уже выделенную ссылку, ведь она всегда одна.